# Getting NoClassDefFoundError in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing an app in **YouTube VideoPlayer**. I am able to run it suceesfully . But when I integrate this in another android application, getting below error. Iam able to run it in marshmallow, but When I tried to run in Lollipop getting below below exception.

```
  07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: adamas.selfiereporter.gallery.YouTubePlayerActivity
    07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at adamas.selfiereporter.approvedfiles.AllApprovedFilesFragment.callOnlineMediaShowingActivity(AllApprovedFilesFragment.java:144)
    07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at adamas.selfiereporter.approvedfiles.AllApprovedFilesFragment.validateOnItemClickResponse(AllApprovedFilesFragment.java:106)
    07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at adamas.selfiereporter.approvedfiles.AllApprovedFilesFragment.onReceiveNotification(AllApprovedFilesFragment.java:91)
    07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at adamas.selfiereporter.common.FragmentBase$1.onReceive(FragmentBase.java:29)
    07-03 15:46:34.188 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
    07-03 15:46:34.191 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    07-03 15:46:34.191 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    07-03 15:46:34.191 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    07-03 15:46:34.191 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    07-03 15:46:34.192 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    07-03 15:46:34.193 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    07-03 15:46:34.193 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    07-03 15:46:34.193 19813-19813/adamas.selfiereporter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Below  is my Code:**

Error showing at:-

**`Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YouTubePlayerActivity.class);`**

```
 private class MyFragment extends fragment
    {

---------
--------
     private void callOnlineMediaShowingActivity(String filePlayUrl) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YouTubePlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_MEDIA_URL, filePlayUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am not getting error if I use other class in place of **`YouTubePlayerActivity.class`**.

Please some one give me the solution

Comment: Check if you have `YouTubePlayerActivity.class` file

Comment: Check your Youtube Activity in proper package(adamas.selfiereporter.gallery.YouTubePlayerActivity) or not

Comment: getContext() is replace with getActivity()   Both are same, but try       else check the Youtube playerActivity is Added or not in manifest

Comment: @Jeffrey Rajan Yes I got it in my Java folder

Comment: @Raj I added it in my manifest file also

Comment: Are your sure  this method (callOnlineMediaShowingActivity()) was execute

Comment: yes @Raj. I was able execute with another class in place of YouTubeActivity.class

Comment: your package name

Comment: don't know why I got down vote. please tell me why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148214/discussion-between-raj-and-basha).

Comment: checkyour package name

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused when there is a dependent file missing during the Runtime. Try these steps for the fix:

- Go to Build option in menu.Select Clean Build
- Again Click on Build from Menu  and select Build APK from the menu.

  Now take the apk file and run it.Your problem will be fixed.

Comment: but I tried this. But not getting this error in Marshmallow. When I run it in lollipop getting this exception